# Expand nested lists to rows, create headers, and map back to original columns

Tags: python, pandas, list

I would like to expand the nested lists to multiple rows and columns. At the same time, map back the results to the corresponding column values.

The dataframe is like the following.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
'column_name':['income_level', 'geo_level'],
'results':[[[0, 12, 13], [0, 98, 43], [1, 29, 73], [2, 12, 34]], [[0, 78, 23], [1, 56, 67], [2, 67, 34]]]}) 

column_name  |  results
----------------------
income_level | [[0, 12, 13], [0, 98, 43], [1, 29, 73], [2, 12, 34]]
geo_level    | [[0, 78, 23], [1, 56, 67], [2, 67, 34]]
```

The final results I'm looking for are like this. (expanding the nested list to rows and columns and matching the corresponding column values)

```
column_name  | num |pct | index
income_level | 0   | 12 | 13 
income_level | 0   | 98 | 43
income_level | 1   | 29 | 73 
income_level | 2   | 12 | 34
geo_level    | 0   | 78 | 23
geo_level    | 1   | 56 | 67
geo_level    | 2   | 67 | 34
```

My current code:

```
pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.chain(*df['results'].values.tolist())), columns=['num', 'pct', 'index'])
```

I'm able to expand and create header but I cannot match back to corresponding column values (i.e. the column_name)

Comment: You should post any code you have created to accomplish this. Stack people are more apt to help fix code then write it for you.

Comment: Are you really creating the Dataframe like this in your code, or is it just a random exemple to have something similar ?

Comment: @Joe Thanks for your feedback. I edited my question and put on my current code

Comment: @Benoit Drogou It's sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Explode` column `results` and assign to `df1`. Create the new dataframe from list of sublist of `df1.results` and `reset_index`

```
df1 = df.explode('results')
pd.DataFrame(df1.results.tolist(), 
             index=df1.column_name,
             columns=['num', 'pct', 'index']).reset_index()

Out[562]:
    column_name  num  pct  index
0  income_level    0   12     13
1  income_level    0   98     43
2  income_level    1   29     73
3  income_level    2   12     34
4     geo_level    0   78     23
5     geo_level    1   56     67
6     geo_level    2   67     34
```

---

On pandas < 0.25, use `sum`, `np.repeat`, and `reset_index` to achieve the same thing

```
pd.DataFrame(df.results.sum(), 
             index=np.repeat(df.column_name, df.results.str.len()), 
             columns=['num', 'pct', 'index']).reset_index()

Out[572]:
    column_name  num  pct  index
0  income_level    0   12     13
1  income_level    0   98     43
2  income_level    1   29     73
3  income_level    2   12     34
4     geo_level    0   78     23
5     geo_level    1   56     67
6     geo_level    2   67     34
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution:

Define a "reformatting" function:

```
def reform(row):
    res = pd.DataFrame(row.results, columns=['num', 'pct', 'index'])
    res.insert(0, 'column_name', row.column_name)
    return res
```

Then apply it and concatenate results:

```
lst = df.apply(reform, axis=1).tolist()
pd.concat(lst).reset_index(drop=True)
```